# C++: Optimized atomics for a rapid single-producer multiple-consumer environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I'm currently on a project which has quite tight loops and real-time requirements. Premature optimization is definitely not a vice here. I want to exploit the possible `relaxed` options of C++ atomics as much as possible to achieve my goals. Here is my (**thread-unsafe**) setup:

```
// Shared data structure
uint8 data[100];
uint64 timeStamp = 0;

// Consumer threads 1...N run this
void loopConsume() {
    uint64 lastTimeStamp = 0;
    uint8 localData[100];
    for (;;) {
        while (timeStamp == lastTimeStamp);
        memcpy(localData, latestData.data, 100);
        lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        doSomething(localData);
    }
}

// Producer callback (singleton)
void produce(uint8 *newData) {
    memcpy(latestData.data, newData, 100);
    latestData.timeStamp++;
}
```

Here is a clumsy (but ostensibly, correct) attempt at making it thread-safe (and thread-correct) using 2 default **sequential consistency** atomics:

```
#include <atomic>

// Shared variables
uint8 data[100];
std::atomic<uint64> timeStamp = 0;
std::atomic<int32> numReaders = 0; // -1 means producer is writing

// Consumer threads 1...N run this
void loopConsume() {
    uint64 lastTimeStamp = 0;
    uint8 localData[100];
    for (;;) {
        uint64 t = timeStamp.load();
        while (t == lastTimeStamp) t = timeStamp.load();
        lastTimeStamp = t;
        for (;;) {
            int32 r = numReaders.load();
            if (r >= 0 && numReaders.compare_exchange_weak(r, r + 1))
                 break; 
        }
        memcpy(localData, data, 100);
        doSomething(localData);
        numReaders.fetch_sub(1);
    }
}

// Producer callback (singleton)
void produce(uint8 *newData) {
    while (!numReaders.compare_exchange_weak(0, -1));
    memcpy(data, newData, 100);
    timeStamp.fetch_add(1);
    numReaders.store(0);
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of atomic operations, all of which by default use sequential consistency. I'm fairly certain many of them can be relaxed. But which ones? Can I get away with fewer operations or a simpler setup?

Another question is contention. I expect there to be few readers and for them to copy over their data to their local variable quickly. Is there then any real advantage to having a kind read-write lock (as above), or just a regular mutex? If a regular mutex is faster in this case, can I get away with incorporating it into the time stamp atomic variable somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you may be interrested in this talk from cppcon 2016: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IB57wIf9W1k - JF Bastien: No Sane Compiler Would Optimize Atomics.

Comment: You don't tell us what kind of hardware you will run this on. On an x86 system the weak and strong versions will likely be identical, and the hardware cache synchronization gives you sequential consistency, whether you ask for it or not (except *maybe* for memory_order_relaxed).

Comment: This kind of code will perform *terribly* on many x86 CPUs. You are wrong about premature optimization not being a vice here, this is where you can do the most damage by optimizing without understanding what you're making the CPU do. Are you seriously trying to use a compare and exchange function to *WAIT*? Are you crazy? (Do you know that they're unconditional writes on most x86 CPUs? Do you know what they do to inter-core buses? Do you know how they interact with hyper-threading? If not, WHY ARE YOU USING THEM? If so, WHY ARE YOU USING THEM!)